# How to calculate the cout of each alphabet in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with some 39000 words. I need to count the number of occurrences of each letter in the list and store them in a dictionary with the alphabets as keys and the number of occurrences as values. How to do it?

The list in question is

```
['voluptuous',
 'outbreak',
 'starched',
 'sharpest',
 'widens',
 'briefcase',
 'stag',
 'gracias',
 'complexes',
 'magnum',
 'classifying',
 'eloquent',
 'forecasters',
 'shepherd',
 'vestments',
 'indestructible',
 'chartres',
 'condemning',
 'closet',
 'davis',
 'students',
.
.
.
```

So, the expected output should be something like this

```
{'a': 2433,
 'b': 5717,
 'c': 1236,
 'd': 12255,
 'e': 35170,
 'f': 4118,
 'g': 8630,
 'h': 7327,
 'i': 26075,
 'j': 6430,
 'k': 2965,
 'l': 16703,
 'm': 8672,
 'n': 22630,
 'o': 19199,
 'p': 8543,
 'q': 5325,
 'r': 22104,
 's': 23730,
 't': 20649,
 'u': 10196,
 'v': 3427,
 'w': 2799,
 'x': 828,
 'y': 5344,
 'z': 1031}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

this is a variant using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

words = ['voluptuous',
 'outbreak',
 'starched',
 'sharpest',
 'widens',
 'briefcase',
 'stag',
 'gracias',
 'complexes',
 'magnum',
 'classifying',
 'eloquent',
 'forecasters',
 'shepherd',
 'vestments',
 'indestructible',
 'chartres',
 'condemning',
 'closet',
 'davis',
 'students']

for word in words:
    counter += Counter(word)
```

or in one line:

```
counter = Counter(char for word in words for char in word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter()` and `chain.from_iterable()`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

lst = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']

Counter(chain.from_iterable(lst))
# Counter({'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2})
```